# What program would be necessary to stream video files to nearby ATSC tuners?

Tags: video, television, boxee, tv-tuner

I have a Boxee Box with the ATSC tuner and I wanted to stream to it through a free local channel I would set up hosted from my house.  First of all, for those who don't know, an ATSC tuner is a little antenna that recieves free HD channel signals going around.  I have seen many ways to set up a TV station, but they are all pirated analog and illegal, and none are ATSC.  The best tutorial I've found is this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqstPGKvTO0

I don't know whether I need a certain program or transmitter to send the ATSC signal to the tuner (and other tuners in the area), or if I use a small receiver as the one in the video.

Please help!  >_<

Answer (score 0):

Try using a normal TV signal with a normal transmitter, maybe it will pick up.  Or try the RED5 server for streaming.